# How to use Page indicator with Slider For futureBuilder

Tags: flutter, slider, indicator

I am trying to have something work like this, if i scroll the Slider (Accounts Slider) The smooth page indicator should follow suit and indicate that there was a movement on the Slider.

The image is Looking thus

[image: Screenshot-1664943674.png]

That is to say, if i move from first Slider to second Slider, the Smooth Page indicator should leave the first and go to the second, that is what i mean

My code is looking like this

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:smooth_page_indicator/smooth_page_indicator.dart';

//Account Details

class AccountDetails {
  String? address;
  String? balance;
  String? coin_name;

  AccountDetails({
    this.address,
    this.balance,
    this.coin_name,
  });

  AccountDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    address = json['address'];
    balance = json['balance'];
    coin_name = json['coin_name'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['address'] = address;
    data['balance'] = balance;
    data['coin_name'] = coin_name;
    return data;
  }
}

//Transaction Details.

class TransactionDetails {
  String? avatar;
  String? name;
  String? date;
  String? amount;

  TransactionDetails({
    this.avatar,
    this.name,
    this.date,
    this.amount,
  });

  TransactionDetails.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    avatar = json['avatar'];
    name = json['name'];
    date = json['date'];
    amount = json['amount'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = <String, dynamic>{};
    data['avatar'] = avatar;
    data['name'] = name;
    data['date'] = date;
    data['amount'] = amount;
    return data;
  }
}

//Transaction Details stuff

Future<List<TransactionDetails>> fetchAlbum() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/people/people.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => TransactionDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

// Account Details stuff.

Future<List<AccountDetails>> fetchAccountDetails() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
      'https://brotherlike-navies.000webhostapp.com/address/addr.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final List result = json.decode(response.body);
    return result.map((e) => AccountDetails.fromJson(e)).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load data');
  }
}

final _controller = PageController(); //gets the page controller

class BaseScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const BaseScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          "My Bank",
          style: TextStyle(
              fontFamily: "Inter",
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
        leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage:
                NetworkImage('https://placeimg.com/640/480/people'),
          ),
        ),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active_outlined,
                  color: Colors.white, size: 27),
              onPressed: () {})
        ],
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ), //gap or use Padding widget
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15), //apply padding to all four sides
            child: Text(
              "Hello Patrick!",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 10,
          ), //gap
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 200,
            child: FutureBuilder<List<AccountDetails>>(
              future: fetchAccountDetails(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return ListView.builder(
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
                        width: 319,
                        height: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            boxShadow: [
                              BoxShadow(
                                color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 233, 230, 230)
                                    .withOpacity(0.8),
                                spreadRadius: 5,
                                blurRadius: 3,
                                offset: const Offset(
                                    0, 7), // changes position of shadow
                              ),
                            ],
                            color: Colors.green,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(9)),
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            const Text(
                              'Account Balance',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 20,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data![index].balance.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                const SizedBox(
                                  width: 5,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  snapshot.data![index].coin_name.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            const SizedBox(
                              height: 30,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              snapshot.data![index].address.toString(),
                              style: const TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
                } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                }
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          ),

          SmoothPageIndicator(controller: _controller, count: 3), // Smooth page indicator
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
            child: Text(
              "Recent Transactions",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 14,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
              child: Center(
                  child: FutureBuilder<List<TransactionDetails>>(
                      future: fetchAlbum(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data!.length,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return ListTile(
                                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                                    child: Image.network(snapshot
                                        .data![index].avatar
                                        .toString()),
                                  ),
                                  title: Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].name.toString()),
                                  trailing: Text(
                                      snapshot.data![index].amount.toString()),
                                  subtitle: Text(
                                    snapshot.data![index].date.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
                                  ),
                                );
                              });
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Text('${snapshot.error}');
                        }
                        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                      })))
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

What am I missing?